# Parse HTML class in individual items with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to parse HTML, I used the following code but I get all of it in one item instead of getting the items individually

```
var url = "https://subscene.com/subtitles/searchbytitle?query=joker&l=";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes =
   doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
     .Where(n => n.HasClass("search-result"));

foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    string itemx = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes["href"].Value;

    MessageBox.Show(itemx);
    MessageBox.Show(item.InnerText);

}
```

I only receive 1 message for the first item and the second message displays all items

Comment: You question is not clear. You `item` represent the HTML of your single `div class="search-result"`. You second `item.InnerText` will give all the div's html. What are trying to display here?

Comment: Please include an example of the HTML on which your code runs, what you are getting when you run the code on that example, and what you expect when you run the code on that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search the data from the url based on class 'search-result', there is only one node that is returned. Instead of iterating through its children, you only go through that one div, which is why you are only getting one result.

If you want to get a list of all the links inside the div with class "search-result", then you can do the following.

**Code:**

```
    string url = "https://subscene.com/subtitles/searchbytitle?query=joker&l=";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

    List<string> listOfUrls = new List<string>();
    HtmlNode searchResult = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='search-result']");

    // Iterate through all the child nodes that have the 'a' tag.
    foreach (HtmlNode node in searchResult.SelectNodes(".//a"))
    {
        string thisUrl = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisUrl) && !listOfUrls.Contains(thisUrl))
            listOfUrls.Add(thisUrl);
    }
```

**What does it do?**

1. `SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='search-result']")` -> retrieves the div that has all the search results and ignores the rest of the document.
2. Iterates through all the "subnodes" only that have `href` in it and adds it to a list. Subnodes are determined based on the dot notation `SelectNodes(".//a")` (Instead of `.//`, if you do `//`, it will search the entire page which is not what you want).
3. If statement makes sure its only adding unique non-null values.

You have all the links now.

**Fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5aQFp

Answer (score 0):

I think it's how you're looking up and storing the data.  Try:

```
    foreach (HtmlNode link doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue( "href", string.Empty );            
        MessageBox.Show(hrefValue);
        MessageBox.Show(link.InnerText);
    }
```

Comment: This prints Every link in that page. OP is asking for hrefs specifically under the div tag with class 'search-result'.